# Many to Many Relationships with Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

It seems like this question has been asked quite a few times before but all the previous questions are over a year old and just noted that people were working on it.I'm not sure if this has since been resolved.

I have a three models: Site, Flight, FlightDataSet

A site has many flights. A flight has one flightDataSet. A site therefore has many flightDataSets through it's flights.

I am trying to graph these data sets and need to get all the data sets that belong to a specific site.

I tried something like:

```
var flightDataSets =  DS.PromiseArray.create();
this.get('activeSite.flights').forEach(function (flight) {
  earthworkAnalyses.pushObject(flight.get('earthworkAnalysis'));
});
```

Which I though might work because this.get('activeSite.flights') returns a promise but PromiseArray does not like to be populated that way.

If I make flightDataSets a normal array they will sometimes be unfulfilled promises when I need to use them later which doesn't work.

So how can I get all the flightDataSets for a site?

Comment: it depends on the adapter you are using, but usually you need to have both models loaded when you are setting up a relationship. If you are getting a promise, it means you are loading the models too late.

Comment: @MartinMalinda fair enough but I don't want to be loading all of the flightDataSets for performance reasons. I need some way to grab them on the fly.

Comment: You can use RSVP.all() to check when all the relevant datasets are loaded and then you can iterate over them and set up the relationships. But ideal would solution would be to set the relationship right after the flightDataSet model creation... I guess that is not possible for your usecase for some reason?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Really seems like there should be an easier way to do it though!